# Ubuntu 16.04 launcher always on both monitors

Tags: 16.04, launcher, display, multiple-monitors

The launcher is always on both monitors even after I changed the settings.
Please help...

[image: Ubuntu 16.04 launcher bug on dual monitor]

Comment: I have the same issue? Did you find a fix?